Limit of NT-Xent
I've been thinking about the NT-Xent loss function:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{L}_{i,j} = -\log \frac{\exp(\text{sim}(\mathbf{z}_i, \mathbf{z}_j) / \tau)}{\sum_{k=1}^{2N} \mathbb{1}_{[k \neq i]} \exp(\text{sim}(\mathbf{z}_i, \mathbf{z}_k) / \tau)}
\end{equation}
Let's assume $\tau=1$. If we want to minimize the loss, then we want to make the numerator big and the denominator small. It seems like in the numerator, the biggest it can get is $e^1=e$ because, if $\mathbf{z}_i$ and $\mathbf{z}_j$ are pointing in the same direction, their cosine similarity will be $1$.
Okay, so now I want to think about how small the denominator can get. The denominator excludes the case of $k \neq i$, but it still allows for cases when $k = j$, which means that the denominator must be as least as big as the numerator because $e^x > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In all the cases when $k\neq i$ and $k\neq j$, we want to push their cosine similarity to $-1$. This means that the smallest the denominator can be is $e + (2N - 2) \cdot \frac{1}{e}$. Right?
This seems a little odd to me, because I think it means that the minimum loss possible is dependent on the batch size:

I'm used to loss functions that approach $0$ as the network becomes more accurate. But, if I'm understanding this all correctly, this is saying that the loss approaches $-\ln\left(\frac{e}{e\ +\ \frac{2N-2}{e}}\right)$ as my network becomes more accurate, and so if my batch size $N>1$, I have no hope of minimizing my loss to anything less than $-\ln\left(\frac{e}{e\ +\ \frac{2(2)-2}{e}}\right) \approx 0.2395 $, right?
I'm sure I'm missing something, what is it?
Thanks!

In fact, I know I'm missing something because currently I have a loss of 0.03 with N=12.

The wording "the denominator must be as least as big as the denominator" looks suspicious.

Well in general you can always add any constant to a loss function and it wont change the minimizer, only the minimal loss. When training a model you are normally interested in finding such a minimizer. You are intersted in the final neural network, not the final e.g. MSE it can archieve. If it bothers you very much, that the optimal value of the loss $L$ of a theoretically optimal model is some $c>0$, then you could simply consider the alternative loss $L-c$. At a first glance, all of your derivations seems correct, so you could simply subtract your found optimal value.

@AlexRavsky, Ah, good catch :). Fixed typo

@C.Brendel Good point! I agree with the thought of simply subtracting $c$, but how am I empirically getting smaller loss with $N=12$?

Well this constant can be dependant on $N$. As you said, the optimal denominator is $e + (2N-1)\frac 1e$. For larger $N$ this will be larger, so the overall constant smaller. This has a similar flavor to before. Any function $L$ can be modified by eg $L\cdot 1/N$ without changing the minimizer. If the optimal value of $L$ was $c$ before, it is now $c/N$. Also from a quick glance, I dont think $N$ is the batch size, but rather the number of components of the final vector $z$, so is fixed for one architecture.

I think there are $2N$ $\mathbf{z_i}$ vectors (I'm looking at the one proposed in SimCLR).
